# Flatten a partially nested list in Ansible

Tags: ansible, json-query

having such a list:

```
[
  [[[6781,"1"]], "a"],
  [[[6782,"1"]], "b"],
  [[[6780,"1"]], "c"]
]
```

which filter / query would you use to "partially flatten" the list to:

```
[
  [6781,"1", "a"],
  [6782,"1", "b"],
  [6780,"1", "c"]
]
```

I tried this one, which is **NOT** working

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    data: '[
  [[[6781,"1"]], "a"],
  [[[6782,"1"]], "b"],
  [[[6780,"1"]], "c"]
]'
  tasks:
   - debug:
      msg: "{{ data | from_json | flatten}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list composed of lists which you want to flatten. Applying the `flatten` filter to the entire list will not do what you want (as you found out) as it will flatten the entire list to a single level.

What you want is to apply that same filter but individually to each element of your top list. This could eventually be done by looping over your list and constructing the result iteratively using `set_fact`.

But the `map` filter does the job in one go:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ data | from_json | map('flatten') }}"
```

Some usefull references:

- [Data manipulation with ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)
- [The jinja2 `map` filter documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map)